# Issue splitting string with jQuery/Javascript if there is only one word or no space in the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `.split` to extract only the first name from a string which *usually* has a first and last name. This works great as long as there is a space present in the string (i.e. first and last names), but when there is only a first name, I get the whole string doubled.

Example:

I have a string which contains the name "John Smith". When I use the code below, it returns "John". Great! But if the string is just "John" and the code is used, "JohnJohn" is returned. NO!

With this line, the js will return 'John'

```
<p>Name: <span class="vName">John Smith</span></p>
```

With this line, the js will return 'JohnJohn'

```
<p>Name: <span class="vName">John</span></p>
```

And the script:

```
<script>
var designerName = $('.vName').text();
designerName = designerName.split(" ")[0];
</script>
```

Here it is on jsfiddle and it works fine there using same jQuery version (v1.8.2): http://jsfiddle.net/5yrYj/1

Running Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m. I don't understand why it wouldn't be working in my script.

Here's the full function:

```
function saveDesign(){
var shaftRender = $('#shaft-image-md').attr('class');
var gripRender = $('#grip-image-md').attr('class');
var labelRender = $('#label-image-md').attr('class');

gripRender = gripRender.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
labelRender = labelRender.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});

var designerShaft = shaftRender+gripRender+labelRender;
var designerName = $('.vName').text();

//Grab only first name
designerName = designerName.split(" ")[0];
//if((/ /).test(designerName)){ designerName = designerName.split(" ")[0]; }
//designerName = (/ /).test(designerName) ? designerName.split(" ")[0]
                                    //: designerName;

$.post("saveDesign.php",
{
  name: designerName,
  shaft: designerShaft,
});

//Debug
alert(designerName); //This displays "JohnJohn"
}
```

No matter which of the three .split lines I use, I still get the double name if the original designerName string does not have a last name = a space. And the alert will display 'JohnJohn' at that point too.

So, how can I call the `.split` code ONLY if there is a space in the string? Or is there another solution which is better suited for my purpose? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

**RESOLVED:** There was an extra instance of .vName in the html. Removed and now working as it should. Thanks to Francisco Afonso for proposing that was the issue.

Comment: `"John".split(" ")[0]` is still `"John"`.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Currently using jquery v1.8.2

Comment: @xdazz if in the example designerName is "John" then the '.split' returns "JohnJohn"

Comment: @aethergy This won't happen.

Comment: Can't replicate that behavior in jquery v1.8.2. What browser (and version) are you using? On what OS (and version)? Can you provide the code for the element with class `.vName`? Can you replicate the behavior on http://jsfiddle.net/ (and share that link back here)?

Comment: @GitaarLAB Thanks. I've updated my question with jsfiddle link and html. Using latest Chrome on Win 7. Can't figure out why it isn't working in my code :/

Comment: Hmm, I tested your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5yrYj/1 (in palemoon = firefox), and I got the expected result: alertbox with 'John' (so no 'JohnJohn'). Please specify the exact and full Chrome-version so others with this combination can test it.

Comment: Updated post. Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're consuming text value from all elements with class = vName.
You have two elements with that class so you're consuming a concatenation of their values.
So: "JohnJohn Smith"
And there is the bug.

Comment: There is only one element with vName class in the working code. I used those two lines in the example to show how they were behaving differently depending on whether there is just a first name or a first and last name

Comment: Give us a link to the working code so that we can check if that's true.

Comment: You were right! I found another instance of .vName way down at the bottom of the html. +1 for discovering the root issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf` or some other function that first checks if a space exists in the string. Check if all browsers support it though, as indexOf might not work with IE8 or below.

```
if (myvar.indexOf(' ') !== -1) {
    myvar = myvar.split(' ')[0];
} else {
    //No space so ignore...
}
```

This isn't jQuery and it doesn't have to be. jQuery is a great framework and I recommend it for most projects, but try and use native JavaScript whenever you can. It's generally faster and you can learn more about the language behind jQuery.

If you really want to use jQuery, you might want to try `$.inArray()` to check if your split worked.

Comment: `.indexOf()` doesn't return `true` or `false` so this won't work.  It returns a numeric index or `-1`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oops. I have another language on the brain. Fixed.

Comment: `String.prototype.indexOf()` is supported in IE8. You may have confused it with `Array.prototype.indexOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

This simple (pure javascript) cross-browser line calls 'the .split code ONLY if there is a space in the string' (like you asked):

```
if((/ /).test(designerName)){ designerName = designerName.split(" ")[0]; }
```

OR:

```
designerName = (/ /).test(designerName) ? designerName.split(" ")[0]
                                        : designerName;
```

It is a ternary if statement (syntax: `(test) ? true : false;`), where `test` returns `true` or `false` when it tests the string referenced by `designerName` on the regex `/ /` (one space).
Example [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6bW39/).

Comment: Bummer. They both return 'JohnJohn'. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: So this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bW39/2/ *still* gives an alertbox with 'JohnJohn' on your computer (using Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m on Win7) ??? That's a very interesting bug!

Comment: No, in my code on my server is the only place I'm getting the 'JohnJohn' result. jsfiddle works fine every time with my code and yours.

Comment: Ahhhh. `<sanity='restored' />`. In that case we'd need more code. My first guess would be function(?) doesn't reach that part of the code. You can look at your error-console to search for errors. You can also start placing some `alert` or `console.log` pieces in your code to see when the code did what.    I also recommend jslint (over jshint).    Good luck on debugging!

Comment: I've updated my post with the full function and more detail. Thanks for your help.